# How do I put this script to auto logout?

Tags: javascript

I want this javascript to auto logout instead button to press it.
Or if any shorter javascript for this exist.
I need this for one my tool that I am trying to create.

```
<?php

session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
else
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;

echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views'];

?>

<!doctype html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function logoutck() {
    var r = confirm("Do you really want to log out?");
    if (r) {
       window.location.href = 'logout.php'
    }
}

</script>

<input id="button1" type='button' onclick='logoutck();' value='LOGOUT'/>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use setTimeout function to call logoutck after some seconds,

Comment: Pls do write answer with full script, im just a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you want display logout confirmation after 3 seconds

```
setTimeout(logoutck, 3000);
```

You can read full document about the function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Good luck!